# GenSA optimization with 2 unknowns

Tags: r, optimization

I'm still relatively new to R and stuck on an optimization problem. I have a rather general question here. I am trying to minimize a function, something like

> `function(a,b){2*a^2+b},`

with two unknowns using the GenSA function. Whenever I try running it, it tells me that it couldn't find b. Now I'm wondering if it is even possible to use GenSA with 2 unknowns or if a different function would be better suited? It would be great if someone had an idea!

The code I'm using for the GenSa function Looks something like this by the way (tried it with a vector too, but didn't work either):

```
> library(GenSA)
> 
> minim<-function(a,b){2*a^2+b}
> 
> dimension <- 30

> global.min <- 0 
> tol <- 1e-15
> 
> lower <- rep(0, dimension)
> 
> upper <- rep(30, dimension)
> 
> 
> out <- GenSA(lower = lower, upper = upper, fn = minim,
> control=list(threshold.stop=global.min+tol,verbose=TRUE))
> 
> out[c("value","par","counts")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2 dimensional problem, not a thirty dimensional one. Obviously not very exciting as the algorithm finds the optimal solution easily. Of course for most problems that is not the case.

```
> minim<-function(a){2*a[1]^2+a[2]}
> dimension<-2
> global.min <- 0
> tol <- 1e-15
> lower <- rep(0, dimension)
> upper <- rep(30, dimension)
> out <- GenSA(lower = lower, upper = upper, fn = minim,
+              control=list(threshold.stop=global.min+tol,verbose=TRUE))
Initializing par with random data inside bounds
It: 1, obj value: 0
> out[c("value","par","counts")]
$value
[1] 0

$par
[1] 0 0

$counts
[1] 32

>
```